# How to add 2 text views in ParseQueryAdapter list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, parse-platform

I am looking to create a list containing 2 text views with data obtained from the parse.com cloud. 
The two text views are : 
1. Normal text(Say A)
2. Text composed of two date objects formatted into strings(Say B)

I am using the following code for this :

ADAPTER

```
public class TripListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Trips> {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyy");
    public TripListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Trips>() {
            public ParseQuery<Trips> create() {
                // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                // only top-rated meals.
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Trips");
                query.whereEqualTo("user", currentUser);
                //query.whereContainedIn("rating", Arrays.asList("5", "4"));
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(Trips trips, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_trip_list, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(trips, v, parent);

        //ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        //ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
        //if (photoFile != null) {
            //mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            //mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                //@Override
                //public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                    // nothing to do
            //  }
            //});
        //}

        TextView destinationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trip_destination);
        destinationTextView.setText(trips.getDestination());
        TextView durationTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.trip_duration);
        durationTextView.setText(formatter.format(trips.getStartDate())+" - "+formatter.format(trips.getEndDate()));
        return v;
    }
```

Trips.java

```
public class Trips extends ParseObject {

    public Trips() {
        // A default constructor is required.
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return getString("to");
    }

    public void setDestination(String title) {
        put("to", title);
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return getString("start");
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date dateObj) {
        put("start", dateObj);
    }

    public String getEndDate() {
        return getString("end");
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date dateObj) {
        put("end", dateObj);
    }
}
```

FRAGMENT WITH LIST VIEW CODE

```
ListView mTripsList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.trips_list);
        mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<Trips>(getActivity(), Trips.class);
        mainAdapter.setTextKey("to");
        mTripsList.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
```

I am only able to see the first text(A) from above though, not the second one with the formatted date objects(B). How do i fix this ?
Thanks

LIST ITEM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
     >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/trip_destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/trip_duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could u please add that list view row layout file?

Comment: That is just a simple horizontal linear layout with two text views. Nothing special there.

Answer (score 1):

**Try to replace your adapter code**

```
public class TripListAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<Trips> {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

        public TripListAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<Trips>() {
                public ParseQuery<Trips> create() {
                    // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to display
                    // only top-rated meals.
                    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Trips");
                    query.whereEqualTo("user", currentUser);
                    //query.whereContainedIn("rating", Arrays.asList("5", "4"));
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    return query;
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public View getItemView(Trips trips, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
            super.getItemView(trips, v, parent);
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (v == null) {
                holder =new ViewHolder();
                v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.item_trip_list, null);
                holder.destinationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trip_destination);
                holder.durationTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.trip_duration);
                v.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
            }


            //ParseImageView mealImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            //ParseFile photoFile = meal.getParseFile("photo");
            //if (photoFile != null) {
            //mealImage.setParseFile(photoFile);
            //mealImage.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
            //@Override
            //public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
            // nothing to do
            //  }
            //});
            //}

            holder.destinationTextView.setText(trips.getDestination());
            holder.durationTextView.setText(formatter.format(trips.getStartDate()) + " - " + formatter.format(trips.getEndDate()));
            return v;
        }

        class ViewHolder{
            TextView destinationTextView;
            TextView durationTextView;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Do I make any changes in the fragment code also accordingly ?

Comment: no just try to replace your adapter code only and let me know

Comment: I am still getting the same result. I think it has something to do with the settextkey function ?

Comment: please replace this line: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy"); in your adapter code.

Comment: but you have define wrong string format one more y is missing.

Comment: Yes I have added that as well. But it doesn't make any difference. yyy and yyyy are the same.